# Shopping Cart Price Rule for European Union Countries

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules, rules

In **Shopping Cart Price Rule** I can set condition as "Shipping Country" "is" or "is not". I need to extend this condition to all European Union Countries. Since Magento has this configuration in

```
system > configuration > general > countries options
```

there is a way to use it in Shopping Cart Price price condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard feature. For such a rule you should use the ANY type in conditions:

[image]

In case you want to extend the standard condition model, then you should do the rewrite and add the appropriate condition like this:

In class where rewriting `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address`:

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
    $attributes = parent::loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();
    $additionalAttributes = array(
        'eu' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Europe Union Country'),
    );
    $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $additionalAttributes);
    $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

    return $this;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Validate Address Rule Condition
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
{
    $address = $object;
    if (!$address instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address) {
        if ($object->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            $address = $object->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
        }
        else {
            $address = $object->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        }
    }
    // Eu check start
    if ('eu' == $this->getAttribute() && !$address->getEu()) {
        $this->setValue(boolval($this->getValue()));
        $euCountries = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/eu_countries'));
        if (empty($euCountries)) {
            $euCountries = array();
        }
        $isEu = in_array($address->getCountry(), $euCountries);
        $address->setEu($isEu);
    }
    // Eu check end

    return parent::validate($address);
}
```

The field will appear in the conditions:
[image]

Everything should work correctly in the rules:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried this by override the model file Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address in local folder but i have a blank page on cart. Didn't find any error in server log.

Comment: This solution is for the rewrite model and not for the version in local. Here is an example you can use: http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/05/creating-a-shopping-cart-price-rule-condition-for-eu-countries/